# When does this fact involving Lagrange's Theorem hold?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, with subgroups $H$ and $K$, and $H \subseteq K \subseteq G$. Then we have
\begin{equation*}
[G\,:\,H] = [G\,:\,K][K\,:\,H].
\end{equation*}

**Question:** Do we require that $H\subseteq K$ be true for this property to hold, or is it true **for all** subgroups $H$ and $K$? Please give your reason.

Comment: For $[K:H]$ to make sense we need that $K\subseteq H$. Review the definition for it.

Comment: No Dietrich I don't believe that is true.

Comment: @MathDoer2320 What definition do you use then? $[K:H]$ is usually defined as the number of cosets of $H$ in $K$. This requires $H$ to be contained in $K$.

Comment: Lagranges Theorem

Comment: @MathDoer2320 ??? Ok, suppose $G$ is the symmetric group of order 6 and K is a subgroup of order 3 and H is a subgroup of order 2. “Use Lagrange’s theorem” to explain what you think $[K:H]$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do we require that
>   H⊆K
>   be true for this property to hold,

Yes because otherwise the notation $[K:H]$ is not meaningful. One cannot find the index if the cosets are not defined.

> is it true for all subgroups
>   H
>   and
>   K
>   ?

Yes, it is, as long as $H\subseteq K$